# Custom post type adding additional markup

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a template but every time I add a new custom post type (in this example neighborhood) it keeps injecting a new `<ol>` and `<li>` here is the code I currently have and I'm using the ACF Advanced Custom Fields plugin to create my custom fields.

```
<?php

/*

  Template Name: Neighborhoods Page

*/

include(TEMPLATEPATH."/header-internal.php");?>

  <div class="container-space"></div>

    <div class="container-main">

    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'neighborhoods'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>


    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

      <ol class="col-neigh-title neighborhood">
        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'url_neighborhood' ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'neighborhood_name' ); ?></a>
        </li>
      </ol>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>There are no posts or pages here</p>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand i paste my code in one way and this forum formats it a different way this is not my code and i won't be able to illustrate my point accurately if it does this.

Comment: There's the WYSIWYG editor that you should use. The "forum" (which is no forum, but a Q/A site) itself uses MarkDown to format content.

Comment: you're inserting a new ol and li for each post in the loop, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @MARS Please edit your question. I can't read a question in there. Your comment to Milo didn't help clarifying it.

Comment: yeah i'm posting my question and it gets formatted in a non-clear way. I want to keep adding <li> elements because essentially it's a list of neighborhoods but if i don't state that's it's an <li> within an <ol> from the beginning how will the template know that's what i want inserted. I see based on Milo's post that it keeps inserting a new OL and LI each time a post or Neighborhood (in this case is added), how do i avoid that but still have it format into a list? Is that better?

Comment: @kaiser i see that it's a WYSIWYG and i just realized that there's no need to add the get_header nor get_footer; i see that now.

Comment: @kaiser i also did ask the question initially it just removed my <ol> and <li> tags from the question essentially not making sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the issue is that anything within the `while` loop will get repeated *for each post*. If you want to wrap *all posts* in a single set of `<ol></ol>` tags, those must go *outside* that `while` statement.

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    // open the <ol> outside the loop
    echo '<ol class="col-neigh-title neighborhood">';

    // anything inside here is repeated for each post
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'url_neighborhood' ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'neighborhood_name' ); ?></a></li>

        <?php
    endwhile;

    // close the <ol> outside the loop
    echo '</ol>';

endif;
```

Comment: good thought, didn't work for me though. I am that new though that i didn't know that's how the loop worked. You gave me food for thought though and for that thank you.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question then!

Comment: I figured out the solution using your concept of moving the <ol> out of the loop and figured it out, I don't know if it's good practice to edit the original post to insert the solution? Thanks Milo.

Answer (score 0):

'neighborhoods'
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        ?>

```
    <ol class="col-neigh-title neighborhood">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


        <li><a href="<?php the_field( 'url_neighborhood' ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'neighborhood_name' ); ?></a>
        </li>


    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

         </ol>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: why does it cut off my code when i paste it? That's weird.

Comment: each line of code must have 4 spaces to format it as a block. the `{}` button does this for you, click the `?` for help and it will explain how to properly format. otherwise this is basically exactly the same as my answer, I just left out the query part, that was implied, perhaps that wasn't clear. one issue with your code though- `if ( have_posts() )` should be `if ( $the_query->have_posts() )`, you're calling that method on a different query without specifically targeting your custom query, it just happens to work in this case.

Comment: @Milo Thanks for the tip i haven't gotten around to exploring the "$the_query" in detail yet but it's on my list.

Comment: `$the_query` is just the variable that you've assigned your custom query to, it could be anything, like `$cheeseburgers`. When interacting with your custom query, you have to reference that query object. If you use the query functions like `have_posts()` without referencing a query object, they operate on the global `$wp_query`, which is the default query WordPress runs on every page request. In the case of your example, `$wp_query` contains the data for the page you're running this custom query on- whatever page you've assigned this Neighborhoods Page template to.

Comment: @Milo that makes great sense thanks for tying that together for me This notion of custom queries is neat i'll look into understanding that more.